# replacing multiple line with singe word using perl

Tags: regex

```
[root@localhost test]# perl -e 'undef $/;while (<>) {s/\<|[a-zA-Z]|\>|\//one/gs;print}' file


oneoneoneoneoneoneoneoneoneoneoneone

oneoneoneoneoneoneoneoneoneoneoneone

oneoneoneoneoneoneoneoneoneoneoneone
```

I need only one need to get print

[root@localhost test]# cat file.input

```
                   <tag>X</tag>
                   <tag>Y</tag>
                   <tag>Z</tag>
```

[root@localhost test]# cat file.output

```
                    one
```

[root@localhost test]#

Comment: Something like `s/[<>a-zA-Z\/]+/one/g`  ?

Comment: nopes actually its doing the same it's replacing every line by one,but i need to replace all the line with single line i.e one

Comment: Try this `s/<(\w+)\s*>[^>]*?<\/\1\s*>(?:\s*<\1\s*>[^>]*?<\/\1\s*>)*/one/g`. And, the one liner, not so sure about, could be this: `perl -e '$/ = ""; $_ = <>; s/<(\w+)\s*>[^>]*?<\/\1\s*>(?:\s*<\1\s*>[^>]*?<\/\1\s*>)*/one/g; print;' file`

Comment: @sln it's working as expected,can you please explain the above.

Comment: Thank You @sln i have understand the concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some explanation:

```
 <                             # Opening tag
 ( \w+ )                       # (1), tag name
 \s*                           # Whitespaces: tab,space,newlines, etc.. 
 > [^>]*? </ \1 \s* >          # Some text then Closing tag
 (?:                           # Cluster group
      \s*                           # Whitespaces: tab,space,newlines, etc..
      <                             # Repeat as above, with tag name
      \1                            #    ""
      \s*                           #    ""
      > [^>]*? </ \1 \s* >          #    ""
 )*                            # End cluster, do 0 to many times
```